# DateComponentsFormatter string(from:) returned nil in crash report

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, time-format, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I have a crash log that indicates that my app crashed on a line with a forced unwrap of the optional.

```
func formattedTimeString(from seconds: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional

    return formatter.string(from: seconds)!
}
```

Note the code above has been simplified to focus on essential components.

The [documentation on that method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1409040-string#discussion) does not mention how the return value could ever be nil, despite having an optional return value. I tested negative and very large input values, but it does not return nil. How can I reproduce this bug?

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633850/nsdatecomponentsformatters-stringfromdate-todate-returns-nil) is the only similar example I could find so far, but I don't think that applies to my situation (and I don't see that error message in the crash report). And this crash has only happened a few times, in a spot that is called very frequently (with different `TimeInterval` inputs).

Comment: Does the simplified posted code really represent the actual code with regard to the formatter? If you have a bug, then simplifying the code here will make it nearly impossible for someone to help narrow down when you might get `nil` as a result. It might be better to post your actual code and only remove code that has no effect of any kind on the formatter.

Comment: The code is accurate.

Comment: Why force unwrap then? You know it's optional. Handle it properly by checking for `nil` and returning some other value if it is. Never force unwrap optionals.

Comment: I don't want to have to redundantly deal with checking for nil everywhere this shared method is called. I can very easily handle the nil here by returning an appropriate output, but it would be much better if I could reproduce the input that creates this issue. The code with the forced unwrap is just there to indicate why the crash occurred. Clearly, it was not safe to assume it would never be nil.

Comment: The problem may only happen with some bizarre locale setting. But in the meantime, code defensively: `return formatter.string(from: seconds) ?? ""`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the crash happens at `formatter.string(from: seconds)!` ? Can you show (a relevant part of) the crash report/stack backtrace?

Comment: Yes, it occurs on that line. 
Just says:  Crashed: main EXC_BREAKPOINT and the memory address, and the method signature as well as the calls leading up to the crash.
(This is on Fabric)